# Running and automation using PySimpleGui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

This is the automation I was talking about, I am not sure how you would use PySimpleGUI to run this automation in Jupyter Notebooks.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/602031/Desktop/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://synchro.chs.spawar.navy.mil/synchro/")
driver.maximize_window()

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.hexagon.pointer[onclick^='login'][onclick*='LoginCACSynchro'][onclick*='SYNCHRO']"))).click()
except:
    time.sleep(15)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.hexagon.pointer[onclick^='login'][onclick*='LoginCACSynchro'][onclick*='SYNCHRO']"))).click()
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="synchronavigation"]/ul[1]/li[6]/a'))).click()
except:
    time.sleep(15)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="synchronavigation"]/ul[1]/li[6]/a'))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="synchronavigation"]/ul[1]/li[6]/ul/li[2]/a'))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="synchronavigation"]/ul[1]/li[6]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[6]/a'))).click()
/*[@id="synchronavigation"]/ul[1]/li[6]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[6]/a'))).click()
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Try to use method `window.perform_long_operation` to run your another code. This method uses THREADS... this means you CANNOT make any GUI calls from
the function you provide with the exception of one function, `Window.write_event_value`.

Comment: how would that work with this selenium automation? Added selenium code.

Comment: Define function to execute relative selenium code after event generated in GUI  by calling `window.perform_long_operation`.

Comment: Jason, I am not sure how to implement what you are saying with a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code demo the way to call `window.perform_long_operation` with selenium library.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import InvalidArgumentException
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def get_url(window, driver, url):
    try:
        driver.get(url)
    except InvalidArgumentException as e:
        window.write_event_value("Exception", e)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"D:\Python\Project\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()

layout = [
    [sg.Text("URL:"), sg.Input(key="URL"), sg.Button("Get")],
    [sg.Multiline("", size=(20, 10), expand_x=True, key='Status')],
]
window = sg.Window("Selenium", layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    print(event, values)
    if event == 'Get':
        window['Status'].update('')
        window['Get'].update(disabled=True)
        url = values["URL"].strip()
        window.perform_long_operation(lambda window=window, driver=driver, url=url:get_url(window, driver, url), "Get Done")
    elif event == 'Get Done':
        window['Get'].update(disabled=False)
    elif event == 'Exception':
        e = values[event]
        window['Status'].update(e)

driver.close()
driver.quit()
window.close()
```